# How can I insert a new div for every 3 records in Rails and Foundation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, zurb-foundation

I'm displaying a customer's assets on their page and for every 3 assets that exist I want to wrap them in a `<div class="row"></div>`.

Right now I have this in my view:

```
<% if @assets.empty? %>
  <h3>You don't have any uploaded images.</h3>
<% else %>
  <% for asset in @assets %>
    <% assetcount += 1 %>
    <div class="large-4 columns assetColumn text-center">
    <a href="#" class="asset-toolbar"><%= image_tag asset.file_name.url(:thumb).to_s %></a>
    <div id="asset-toolbar-options<%= assetcount %>" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal<%= assetcount %>" data-reveal><span data-tooltip class="has-top tip-top radius" title="Enlarge Image"><i class="icon-zoom-in"></i></span></a>
      <%= link_to [current_customer, asset], method: :delete do %>
        <span data-tooltip class="has-top tip-top radius" title="Delete Image"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal<%= assetcount %>" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <%= image_tag asset.file_name.to_s %>
    </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I tried using the `split_each(3)` but it completely screwed up my layout. And then I tried using the `assetcount` to keep track of it but mind exploded :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [Enumerable#each_slice](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice)

```
<% @assets.each_slice(3) do |assets_by_3| %>
  <div class='row'>
    <% assets_by_3.each |asset| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why you are using assetcount.

you can use ruby [each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) , so your view will be something like this

```
<% if @assets.empty? %>
  <h3>You don't have any uploaded images.</h3>
<% else %>
  <% @assets.each_slice(3) do |group_assets| %>
   <div class="row"></div>
     <% group_assets.each do |asset| %>
    <div class="large-4 columns assetColumn text-center">
    <a href="#" class="asset-toolbar"><%= image_tag asset.file_name.url(:thumb).to_s %></a>
    <div id="asset-toolbar-options<%= assetcount %>" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal<%= assetcount %>" data-reveal><span data-tooltip class="has-top tip-top radius" title="Enlarge Image"><i class="icon-zoom-in"></i></span></a>
      <%= link_to [current_customer, asset], method: :delete do %>
        <span data-tooltip class="has-top tip-top radius" title="Delete Image"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal<%= assetcount %>" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <%= image_tag asset.file_name.to_s %>
    </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```